# Messages in TCPstream get mixed up with each other

Tags: rust, tcp

I have a small tcp client and server, they run on each their device.
The client looks like this:

```
fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream)-> Result<(), Error>   {
    for i in 1..1000 {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(2000));
        let uplink = encrpyt(&[1;33], &i_c_i_cpy);
        stream.write_all(&uplink);(&uplink);
        println!("uplinklen {}",uplink.len());
}
fn main() {



    match TcpStream::connect("192.168.1.227:8888") {
        Ok(mut stream) => {
            println!("Successfully connected to server");
            handle_connection(stream);
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Failed to connect: {}", e);
        }
    };
}
```

The encryption function just returns a vector, that is encrypted and encoded. So It's just a vector.

THe server looks like this:

```
fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream)-> Result<(), Error>   {
        loop {
            println!("start reading input");
            let mut buf = [0;46];
            stream.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
            let incoming = &buf;
            println!("getting {:?}", incoming);
}

fn main() {

    // static key material of r (stored in efuse)


    let listener = TcpListener::bind("192.168.1.227:8888").unwrap();


    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        handle_connection(stream);
    }
}
```

and this is just the client sending a bunch of messages to the server.

THe encryption function always outputs a start of `7,0`, but if I run these two for a while, the after about a minute or so, I start to see these inputs at the server:

```
getting [43, 196, 203, 62, 25, 251, 78, 211, 7, 0, 24, 32, 88, 41, 59, 70, 187, 214, 222, 9, 217, 240, 4, 174, 221, 222, 77, 34, 199, 32, 160, 105, 199, 249, 108, 2, 29, 211, 83, 110, 85, 161, 69, 160, 9, 45]
```

Where I can see that the message has been moved a bit, and prepended with a part of another message.
So, the server is getting the messages out of order. I actually thought I had this fixed by sending fixed length messages, and always reading into a bufffer of that size.

When looking around a common solution for this type of problem is to use `BufReader`, but all the bufreader examples I can find send pure string messages,  and have messages where the input doesnt not include EOF's, and the vectors I need to send, needs to be able to contain all type of ´u8´'s.

How can I send messages over tcp, without them getting mixed together?

It is worth noting that this problem is especially bad when I run the client on my esp32 wroom

Comment: Note that ``write`` is not guaranteed to write everything, but returns how much has been written. Use ``write_all`` to send an entire message at once.

Comment: I'm guessing that `encrpyt` returns 46 bytes?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi oh, yes, my code is actually doing this already: I edited

Comment: @canton7 yes, it retruns 46 bytes

Comment: If you haven't actually run the code in your question, please do that now, and make sure that it reproduces your problem

Comment: it has been run and tested